# Nestjs How I can inject values in body request from session jwt req.user

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have created a "custom decorator" and I use it to inject in the body request the company code (ZON_EMPRESA) from the user of the jwt session.

```
// DECORATOR
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';
export const Zona = createParamDecorator((data, req) => {
    req.body.ZON_EMPRESA = req.user.USU_EMPRESA;
    return req.body;
});
```

Validation does not work in the controller. If I use the standard decorator @Body () validates correctly.
But I can not inject the body with the value ZON_EMPRESA from req.user of jwt session

```
// CONTROLLER
@Put('')
async update( @Zona() body: IZona ) {
    return await this.zonaonaService.update( body );
}

// VALIDATION
import { IsString, Length, IsInt, Min } from 'class-validator';
export class IZona {        
    readonly ZON_CODIGO?: number;

    @IsInt() 
    @Min(1)
    readonly ZON_EMPRESA: number;

    @IsString() 
    @Length(5, 50)
    readonly ZON_NOME: string;

    @IsInt() 
    @Min(1)
    readonly ZON_VENDEDOR: number;
}
```

How can i fix this.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Request Decorators aren't a good fit for what you're trying to accomplish as they are designed for retrieving information from the Request object, not for mutating it. You should use an `interceptor` instead as it will run before the rest of the decorators allowing you to update the Request body properly so that it's automatically picked up by `@Body` and the `ValidationPipe` (which I assume you're using otherwise no validation will occur).

```js
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CompanyCodeInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    call$: Observable<any>,
  ): Observable<any> {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    req.body.ZON_EMPRESA = req.user.USU_EMPRESA;

    return call$;
  }
}
```

Interceptors can be applied at the method, controller or global scope. For example applying it to a single HTTP handler inside your controller:

```js
@Post()
@UseInterceptors(CompanyCodeInterceptor)
exampleHandler(@Body() model: IZona) {
   // model is properly validated here, do whatever
   return model;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse Carter. Your solution is perfect

Comment: @ApicitoDiaz No problem, glad that I was able to help. Feel free to upvote this answer as well so that other people stumbling across this in the future can feel confident

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```ts
// DECORATOR
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';
export const Zona = createParamDecorator((data, req) => {
    req.body.ZON_EMPRESA = req.user.USU_EMPRESA;
    return req.body;
});
```

Use `User` parameters decorator in controller, and fetch this information from user, and pass it to the service.

```ts
// DECORATOR
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';
export const User = createParamDecorator((data, req) => {
    return req.user;
});

// CONTROLLER
@Put('')
async update( @User() user: IUser ) {
    return await this.zonaonaService.update( user.USU_EMPRESA );
}
```

Comment: In my real code I do that same thing. But my problem is not with this but with the ZON_VENDEDOR field that is not validated when I use @Zona() decorator where I do more things that asign value to ZON_EMPRESA

Comment: @ApicitoDiaz so why just don't call validate from class-validtor on entity?

Comment: It seems clearer and more concise to make it work like @Body ().

Comment: I do not understand why with @Body () it does the validation and returns the errors of the fields and my decorator does not